# Tracking issues Inserting and Updating Unidirectional Many to Many object in EF Core 7

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I am trying to add an object to my context. My class layout, db context and add method are below:

classes:

```cs
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public int SportId { get; set; }
    public Sport Sport { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    public int SportId { get; set; }
    public Sport Sport { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Sport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

context:

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{ 
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sport> Sports { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Scrap;User    Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;TrustServerCertificate=true;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasOne(x => x.Sport).WithMany(x =>  x.Players).HasForeignKey(x => x.SportId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany(x => x.Players).WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasMany(x => x.Positions).WithMany();
    }
}
```

Add method:

```cs
using (var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
    context.Teams.Add(team);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

data being added in json:

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Fireball",
  "players": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "jim",
      "positions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Qb"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "WR"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "RB"
        }
      ],
      "sportId": 1,
      "sport": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Football - american",
        "players": [
          {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "joe",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "blake",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "erik",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "joe",
      "positions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Qb"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "WR"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "RB"
        }
      ],
      "sportId": 1,
      "sport": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Football - american",
        "players": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "jim",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          null,
          {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "blake",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "erik",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "blake",
      "positions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Qb"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "RB"
        }
      ],
      "sportId": 1,
      "sport": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Football - american",
        "players": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "jim",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "joe",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "erik",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "erik",
      "positions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Qb"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "WR"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "RB"
        }
      ],
      "sportId": 1,
      "sport": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Football - american",
        "players": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "jim",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "joe",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WR"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          },
          {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "blake",
            "positions": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Qb"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RB"
              }
            ],
            "sportId": 1,
            "sport": null
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "sportId": 1,
  "sport": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Football - american",
    "players": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "jim",
        "positions": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Qb"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "WR"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "RB"
          }
        ],
        "sportId": 1,
        "sport": null
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "joe",
        "positions": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Qb"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "WR"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "RB"
          }
        ],
        "sportId": 1,
        "sport": null
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "blake",
        "positions": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Qb"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "RB"
          }
        ],
        "sportId": 1,
        "sport": null
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "erik",
        "positions": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Qb"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "WR"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "RB"
          }
        ],
        "sportId": 1,
        "sport": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Sports, Players and positions all exist in the database and are valid.

The player position needs to be dynamic at the time of adding a team but I always get the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'Position' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

I have tried attaching the position only once, but that still would throw the same error on save.

I have tried setting the entry state value to unchanged and detached to the same result.

This is using the EF Core shadow table and a unidirectional many to many and nothing I have tried allows me to add bulk amounts of these at the same time with different users, on the same team all having the same position.

Comment: Load. players from database, then replace in Team.Players all players with loaded. Then Add.

Comment: It seems you're not showing the full code: how are you processing the json to added entities? You will likely have to do it in steps: first extract all possible positions, add each unique value to the database and use the tracked entities (e.g. in a dictionary) to form each position array, etc, etc.

Comment: There's a lot of repeated data in your JSON. This is probably confusing EF Core, e.g.: when it goes to add `$.sport.players[0]`, being `{ "id": 8, "name": "jim", ...}`, it cannot because Jim has already been added via `$.players[0]`.